Where to start in creating a patterned Tiled floor
Firstly my apologies if this has been asked before, Blender is very new to me (as is 3d modelling in general) and I'm struggling to find an answer anywhere. This is likely me not searching with the right terminology to get the right results or just a lack of understanding of the program itself.
I am essentially trying to design a tiled floor that is similar to the reference photo.
The majority of the floor consists of plain white tiles, but in some open spaces there is pattern variations (like the ones seen below) made with different tile types and patterns.
I have a single plane that is scaled to fit the entire floor with the white tile texture scaled and mapped to it but i am struggling to understand where to start in  implementing the curved and circular alternative tile patterners.
With some "squarer" sections of the floor where there is a distinct change in pattern i have subdivided the plane and used some loop cuts. I have then assigned a new texture to those parts. Its the curved path type sections that i cant seem to get my head around.
Any help or pointers is greatly appreciated.


Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Sorry, I don’t have a project file as such. I am first just experimenting with planes and the tools before i start anything.

Do you want to use seamless textures for the tiles? For such a large hall you could use the geometry to separate the different patterns. The circle can be created with a Knife Projection operation. Then you can apply a different material. I'm not sure how smooth the result will be... Another approach is to use textures as masks to separate the different patterns.

Thank you for coming back to me. Seamless textures would be the way i would like to go. I will try some of the points you mentioned, especially the masks. Thanks again, it’s really appreciated.
